# how to insert Map to dynamodb table in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am new with dynamodb, I want to insert an Dictionary in one column.In amazon doc for asp.net I see how to insert a single or a list of string, it is easy but now I want to insert Dictionary to column like below

```
   var diffrent_type = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            diffrent_type .Add(i.ToString(), 0);
        }
var table = Table.LoadTable(_amazonDynamoDb, TableName);
var item = new Document();
```

then here I want to assign for example

```
item['specific_att']=diffrent_type;
```

But Document only accepts DynamoDBEntry, here how to solve my problem. I would appreciate to show me the best way for insertion a map data to dynamodb;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Amazon Document instead of Dictionary to put map in dynamodb:

```
var diffrent_type = new Document();
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
 {
   diffrent_type .Add(i.ToString(), 0);
 }
var table = Table.LoadTable(_amazonDynamoDb, TableName);
var item = new Document();
```

and then your code will be right:

```
item['specific_att']=diffrent_type;

await table.PutItemAsync(item);
```

for more info to insert map, see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemsDocumentClasses.html)